# Query of three related tables, showing only the latest records for each person, with SQL in MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, relationship

I have three tables:

**Registrants**

- Registrant ID (Primary key)

**Correspondences**

- Correspondence ID
- Correspondence Time
- Correspondence Date
- Registrant ID (Foreign key)
- Course ID (Foreign key)

**Course**

- Course ID (Primary key)

The idea is that we can record who has registered for which course, whether a course is full and so on, while keeping track of all of the changes along the way and keeping detailed notes for each phone-call, email, fax, etc (there are way more fields than I have shown here).

What I want is a query with one unique Registrant ID and the Course ID in the latest Correspondence record (as determined by Corresponence Time and Date) in each row. So basically I can look at the query and read off something like this:

- "Person A last said he would like to attend Course C at this time and date"
- "Person D last said she would like to attend Course A at this time and date"

Solutions that use SQL or the MS Access 'Design View' UI are both fine.

Comment: where are person name and course name stored?

Comment: @Vikram All of the person's details (name, address, phone number, etc) are in Registrants. All of the course's details (time, date, location, presenter, etc) are in Course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a bunch of parentheses in MS Access.

```
SELECT c1.[correspondence id],
       r.[registrant id],
       c2.[course id],
       [correspondence date] + [correspondence time] AS expr1
FROM   course c2
       INNER JOIN (registrants r
                   INNER JOIN correspondences c1
                     ON r.[registrant id] = c1.[registrant id])
         ON c2.[course id] = c1.[course id]
WHERE  [correspondence id] IN (SELECT [correspondence id]
                               FROM   correspondences b
                               WHERE  b.[registrant id] = c1.[registrant id]
                                      AND [correspondence date] +
                                          [correspondence time]
                                          =
                                          (SELECT MAX([correspondence date] +
                                                      [correspondence time])
                                           FROM   correspondences
                                           WHERE
                                              [registrant id] =
                                              c1.[registrant id]))
```

I would go mad very quickly if I had to work with these tables. Get rid of all the spaces.

Answer (score 2):

This is made more difficult because the date and time are in separate fields.

If you are using the sequential Autonum ID in Access, you can use the CorrespondenceID to indicate the latest one.

Try something like this:

```
SELECT 
  Reg.Name,
  Course.Name,
  C.CorrespondenceDate,
  C.CorrespondenceTime
FROM
  (SELECT MAX(CorrespondenceID) AS ID, RegistrantID, CourseID
     FROM Correspondence
      GROUP BY RegistrantID, CourseID) AS CX
  INNER JOIN Correspondences AS C ON CX.CorrespondenceID = CX.ID
  INNER JOIN Registrants Reg on CX.RegistrantID = Reg.RegistrantID
  INNER JOIN Course ON CX.CourseID = Course.CourseID;
```

If you are not using sequential autonum, you'll have to combine the date and time fields to determine which is the latest.  You could probably substitute `MAX(CorrespondenceDate + CorrespondenceTime)` in the CX Subquery above.

A couple of other things you might consider:

- Use a single DateTime field, populate with Now() will make it easier to determine the latest.
- You have mixed pluralities on the table names "course" (singular) vs "registrants" (plural) - you should probably be consistent - many people prefer singular
- I would consider having a table enrollment which does the mapping between course and registrant, then have correspondence map to enrollment.  It feels a better structure to me.

Comment: I tried the above SQL and Access locked up for a bit until it said: "Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'CX.[Correspondence ID] = CX.ID INNER JOIN Registrants AS Reg ON CX.[Registrant ID] = Reg.[Registrant ID] INNER JOIN Courses ON CX.[Course ID] = Courses.[Course ID'."

Comment: I can't use an autonumber because sometimes things will need to be back-dated.

My understanding is that if I join time and date it is harder to work with in forms and tables (this is probably an Access thing).

I made a typo in my post - the table should be "Courses" as all tables are plurals (maybe this is a bad system but it is consistent at least).

It doesn't make sense to create an extra table just to hold one value.